# "Previous Posts" is Not Working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

For some reason, when you click "Previous Posts" on my wordpress blog, the page URL changes, but the first ten posts are displayed again.

You can see the issue here: http://onedirectionconnection.com/ and then page two http://onedirectionconnection.com/page/2/#sthash.0SQiq9AP.dpbs (that's another thing - I'm not sure why that code is being added at the end of the following page's URL)...

Anyway, here is the code I'm using for my front page template saved in a file called front-page.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Splash Page
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="section-container">
                <h1 class="section-title">Latest News</h1>
            </div>
            <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1'); ?>
            <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title bottommargin big">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h1>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <?php the_content(); ?> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <footer class="row no-margin">
                        <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                            Author: <br>
                            <?php the_author_link(); ?> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                            Posted On:<br>
                            <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                            Categorized:<br>
                            <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry-right">
                            Discussion:<br>
                            <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="section-container">
                <h1 class="section-title">More News</h1>
            </div>
            <?php

                $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'offset' => 1,
                    'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                ));

            ?>
            <?php while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="row topmargin">
                <div class="col-md-3 no-padding center">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'img-thumbnail img-responsive')); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <header class="entry-header">
                            <h1 class="entry-title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </h1>
                        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                            <?php
                                wp_link_pages( array(
                                    'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'professional1d' ),
                                    'after'  => '</div>',
                                ) );
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                    </article><!-- #post-## -->

                    <?php
                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                        if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                            comments_template();
                    ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <footer class="row no-margin">
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Author: <br>
                    <?php the_author_link(); ?> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Posted On:<br>
                    <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry">
                    Categorized:<br>
                    <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 meta-entry-right">
                    Discussion:<br>
                    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php comments_number(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <div class="center">
                <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
            </div>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Everything seems pretty standard so I really have no clue what the issue is. If anyone could help me out with this issue, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After comparing two - three post/pages of your blog. i think, it add the # tag at the end of url. this happen only after loading the entire page. which means it is added by one of your plugin. the plugin may be for "load fresh content from the server instead of the local browser cache"

so first deactivate the plugin you installed for this kind of features

Comment: I deactivated all my plugins and the problem still persisted... are there any other steps I should take?

Comment: I figured out what plugin was adding the hash code at the end of my URLs (it was sharethis). I disabled it and still the problem persists.

Comment: After disabled the plugin.. you need to clear cache & cookies of browser... even need to close the browser.. and reopen with ctrl+f5...